# Fourier transform using contour integral

Tags: fourier-transform, contour-integration

I have to evaluate the Fourier sine integral $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(sx)}{x(a^2+x^2)}\mathrm dx$$

I tried using contour integration using

$$\int_0^∞\frac{\sin(sx)}{x(a^2+x^2)}\mathrm dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_c\frac{e^{isz}}{z(a^2+z^2)}\mathrm dz$$

Which on solving gives me $\frac{\pi i}{a^2}(1-\frac{e^{-as}}{2})$

I have used $ai$ and $0$ as my poles

But the final required solution is
$$\frac{π}{2a^2}(1-e^{-as})$$

Where am I going wrong can someone help me

Comment: I don't understand why 0 is a pole, The poles are at $\pm ai$. You should specify (or at least try to describe) the contour you are taking to solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry it was my typing mistake I've corrected it now

Comment: I've take 0 and $+ai$ since they other lie inside the contour $ 0 to ∞ $

Comment: Yes, I see after you made your edits. Please describe the contour you are taking.

Answer (score 1):

Since the integrand is even:

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(sx)}{x(a^2 + x^2)}dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(sx)}{x(a^2 + x^2)}dx $$

To evaluate it, you can see my post: [Fourier transform of a rational function using contour integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4820349/fourier-transform-of-a-rational-function-using-contour-integration)

It seems to me that your problem is by applying residues theorem: the singularities on the path of integration counts a half of the residue.
I post the solution by hand [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoFze.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn3X4.jpg), i got what is supposed to be obtained.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.